# Why are margins not getting set between flex-items?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have recently started learning flexbox. I am trying to set margins between the divs inside the `.parent` container, but the margin is not displaying. Also, if I give a width value to any of the `.child` divs, they still expand to cover the whole window. Where am I going wrong?

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.parent {
 display: flex;
 height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
 flex: 1;
 width: 32%;
 margin: auto;
 height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid blue;
 background: green;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Flexbox</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the site?

Comment: This is happening because you're specifying `flex: 1;` in your `.child` div.

Comment: margins work for me. as for the width, you can use `max-width`

Comment: I am practicing on localhost. I can make a codepen though. @Hunter Turner: Thanks, removing flex: 1 it worked!

Comment: Is there a way to add margins without removing flex: 1 ? Edit: Figured it out. I can just provide some margins in px or %. Do let me know if there is a better way. thanks.

Comment: margins works fine in flexbox, I can't see the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/jw00ecyb/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `flex: 1;`, which is causing the div's to resize to fill the empty space.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.parent {
 display: flex;
 height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
 width: 32%;
 margin: auto;
 height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid blue;
 background: green;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Flexbox</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

"margins" in flexbox are going to be controlled mainly by the width of your containers, not by specifying margins.  Use `flex-basis` to determine the width of your containers and remove the `flex: 1`. That's what's causing your containers to expand.  And remember it's "flex" box.  it's meant to fluid, so trying to adapt static values for things like margin defeats the purpose.

**Tip**: When debugging use background colors and not borders.  Borders effect width and can cause you trouble. Cheers.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.parent {
 display: flex;
 height: 100px;
 justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
 flex-basis: 20%;
 height: 100px;
 background: green;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Flexbox</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Hunter Turner says if you remove `flex: 1` it will work. This property sets the length of the item relative to the others.

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.parent {
 display: flex;
 height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
 width: 32%;
 margin: auto;
 height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid blue;
 background: green;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Flexbox</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```